# display several rows of a mysql table via php

Tags: php, mysql

I just started php and sql, so this question is probably very silly. I have a database containing nicknames, ids and scores, and I would like to display with php all the nicknames and their corresponding scores, how can I do it ?

So far, I've got this but it only displays one pseudo and its score.

```
<?php
require 'actions/database.php';

$getAllInfos = $bdd->query('SELECT pseudo, score FROM users');
$getAllInfos->execute(array());
$AllInfos = $getAllInfos->fetch();
?>

<body>
    <br><br>
    <div class="container">
        <h2> scores : </h2>
        <br>
        <?php echo $AllInfos['pseudo'] ?> : <?php echo $AllInfos['score'] ?>
    </div>
```

By the way, here is the creation of my database :

```
<?php
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=seio;charset=utf8;', 'root', 'root');
?>
```

Thanks a lot for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Which will give you an array you can loop though.